# Why can't the server find my css file?

Tags: php, css, twig

When I go to my server in my web browser at localhost:8000 I get this error: [404]: /css/styles.css - No such file or directory

```
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title>Repeat Counter!</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Repeat Counter</h1>
  <form action="/results">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="keyword">Enter your keyword:</label>
      <input id="keyword" name="keyword" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="bank">Enter your bank of words to check:</label>
      <input id="bank" name="bank" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn-success">Count</button>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my styles.css file:

```
 .container {
         max-width: 600px;
         margin: auto;
     }
```

My styles.css file is in my css folder, which is in my project root folder. File path : evanbutler/repeatcounter/css/styles.css

And here's a link to the git repository if you wanna look at all the files:
https://github.com/evanb2/Assessment2.git

I feel like I'm making a really simple/obvious error but I just can't see it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I'm an idiot. Just had to move my css folder from the root folder into the web folder with my index.php file, which makes sense because that's where Terminal is running my server from.